# Does faster than light lead to closed timelike curves?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, causality, closed-timelike-curve

If some signal can be sent to a spacelike interval then is it possible in some reference frame to have a close timelike curve? Novikov claims so in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9807067). The argument lies below eq$7$ but essentially (what I understood) it's an event where effect happens before cause (photon striking detector before it's creation).

Moreover, I find it a bit odd on the grounds of topological property of the two different cases. The former is homeomorphism to a straight line ($R^1$) while the latter is homeomorphic to a circle ($S^1$).

Comment: Faster than light signals do not follow time-like curves. You can postulate faster than light particles in Minkowski, but that does not lead to closed time-like curves. Or what do you mean with "sent to a space-like interval"?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're misunderstanding the paper. You refer to a paragraph in section 2, but section 2 is about special relativity, which deals with Minkowski space. There are no closed, timelike curves in Minkowski space.

In section 2, Novikov is simply recapitulating the standard argument that FTL violates causality, and describing the standard tachyonic antitelephone argument. What is being described is a closed *spacelike* curve.

The paper is actually pretty unclear and poorly written IMO. The abstract refers to closed timelike curves, but the body of the paper only ever refers to closed spacelike curves. The other sections besides section 2 are about quantum mechanics on a background of curved spacetime, and they make technical arguments that I don't know enough to comment on. But I think section 2 is a simple recap of freshman physics material.